# Laurent series of $f(z)$ at $z=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

for complex function $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)}$ what is the laurent series about point $z=-1$

I try that
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)}$$

$$=\frac{z}{z+1} \frac{1}{z-1}$$

$$=\frac{z}{z+1} \frac{1}{z-(-1)+(-1)-1}$$

$$=\frac{z}{z+1} \frac{1}{(z+1)-2}$$

$$=\frac{z}{z+1} \frac{1}{z+1} \frac{1}{1- \frac{2}{z+1}}$$

$$=\frac{z}{(z+1)^2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(\frac{2}{z+1})^n}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2^n z}{(z+1)^{n+2}}}$$

is there any mistake here?

it looks strange by comparing with examples in text book...

Comment: The algebra is OK. Since you need all in terms of $(z+1)$ write in the numerators $z = (z+1) -1$ and get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things which could help (I hope and wish) $$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)}=\frac{1}{2 (z+1)}+\frac{1}{2 (z-1)}$$ and so, the Laurent series about point $z=-1$ can write $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2 (z+1)}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{z+1}{8}-\frac{1}{16} (z+1)^2-\frac{1}{32}
   (z+1)^3-\frac{1}{64} (z+1)^4+O\left((z+1)^5\right)$$

Comment: but, why the second part of first equation does not like this? $$\frac{1}{2 (z-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(z+1)-2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z+1}\frac{1}{1- \frac{2}{z+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(\frac{2}{z+1})^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Correction:
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{z+1} \frac{z}{z-1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{z+1} \frac{z+1-1}{z-(-1)+(-1)-1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{z+1} \left(\frac{z+1}{(z+1)-2}-\frac{1}{(z+1)-2}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{(z+1)-2}-\frac{1}{z+1}\left(\frac{1}{(z+1)-2}\right) $$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{z+1}-\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\right) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{2}{z+1}\right)^n}$$
etc.

Note. Your mistake is the $z$ in the sum. It should be in powers of $z+1$ only.